# unknown log wx= wy= rx= ry= ios

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, nslog

Basically i am using calayer in a scrollview from the apple tiles example.

I seem to get this odd output to to the consol(Target output). the reason i say its odd is because it looks like the log you get when you print variables out from a break point as you can see there is no date, time and class at the begin of the log as you would normally get with NSLog.

all my Break points are accounted for. there is no c stile printf in the code. and all my NSLogs are accounted for even though it can not be coming from a NSLog.

I just want to get rid of the logs. Any thoughts?

```
$//add this line to help others find this article
$wx=0, wy=0, rx=0 ry=0

$//here is a real snippet of the log

$wx=0.273110, wy=0.287260, rx=0.632260, ry=0.344220
$gx=0.279140, gy=0.590130, bx=0.122600, by=0.060770
$wx=0.273110, wy=0.287260, rx=0.632260, ry=0.344220
$gx=0.279140, gy=0.590130, bx=0.122600, by=0.060770
$wx=0.273110, wy=0.287260, rx=0.632260, ry=0.344220
$gx=0.279140, gy=0.590130, bx=0.122600, by=0.060770
$wx=0.273110, wy=0.287260, rx=0.632260, ry=0.344220
$gx=0.279140, gy=0.590130, bx=0.122600, by=0.060770
$wx=0.273110, wy=0.287260, rx=0.632260, ry=0.344220
$gx=0.279140, gy=0.590130, bx=0.122600, by=0.060770
$wx=0.273110, wy=0.287260, rx=0.632260, ry=0.344220
```

Comment: Looks like a transaction to me... Maybe a CATransaction?

Comment: @CodaFi how would u get a transition to log like that?

Comment: My bad.  They are actually RBG values if you look close.  Rx, gx, bx/ry,gy,by.  The w's must be the alpha channel then...

Comment: ya but i cant find where they are loggin from :(

Comment: Set a break point and step through, this way you can quickly narrow it down

Comment: @trapper i have stepped through most of it and could not find it

Comment: I'm seeing this too! It's totally bizarre. Has anyone made any progress toward figuring out where they come from? I don't want to leave any logging on when I ship my app for performance reasons.

Comment: i think its a part of one of the apple examples i re built the code my self and it was gone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

could not find it in the end.

i started a new project and copied over the files bit by bit till i had recreated the project without the strange logs.